# Is there any methode to automatically install angular dependencies?

Tags: angular, frameworks

I'm setting up a new framework in witch i used many dependencies and i want to make them automatically downloaded when i install my framework in other projects. how to do that?

For now i'm installing them in each time i install my framework in my projects

When i install the framework i recieve errors about missing dependencies that i used in the framework and i need to reinstall them when installing my framework !! i expect to do so when i install the framework these dependencies are installed automatically?